# Qt - Tricky search algorithm - duplicates or "mirrored" duplicates in a list

Tags: qt, list, search, duplicates

Picture this: I have a JSON file which has a list of `Node` objects that contain a list of `Link` types. Something like:

```
node1:
    links: node1,node2
           node3,node1
           node1,node6

node2:
    links: node2,node1
           node2,node9
           node7,node2
```

I need to identify unique pairs of links - ie a `(node_a,node_b)` pair. Note that `(node_b,node_a)` represents the *same thing*.

The `Link` class has getter methods that return a pointer to either the source/destination `Node`. In the file, the information about the links is stored as a string that has the `source` node's name and the `destination` node name, like: `(source,destination)`.

When I build my structure from file, I first create the `Nodes` and only then I create the `Links`. The `Link` constructor is as follows:

```
Link::Link(Node *fromNode, Node *toNode)
```

And my code to create the links:

```
        QList<Link*> consumedLinks; // list where I was trying to place all the non-duplicate links

        // for each node in the file
        foreach(QVariant nodesMap, allNodesList){
            QVariantMap node1 = nodesMap.toMap();
            QList<QVariant> nodeDetails = node1["node"].toList();
            QVariantMap allLinksMap = nodeDetails.at(9).toMap();

            // extract all the links of the node to a list of QVariant
            QList<QVariant> linksList = allLinksMap["links"].toList();

            // for each Link in that list
            foreach(QVariant linkMap, linksList){
                QVariantMap details = linkMap.toMap();
                Node *savedFromNode;
                Node *savedToNode;

                // get all the Items in the scene
                QList<QGraphicsItem*> itemList = scene->items();

                // cast each item to a Node
                foreach(QGraphicsItem *item, itemList){
                    Node* tempNode = qgraphicsitem_cast<Node*>(item);
                    if(tempNode){
                        // check what the node name matches in the link list
                        if(tempNode->text()==details["fromNode"]){
                            savedFromNode = tempNode;
                        }
                        if(tempNode->text()==details["toNode"]){
                            savedToNode = tempNode;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // create the link
                Link *linkToCheck = new Link(savedFromNode,savedToNode);

                // add it to the links list (even if duplicate)
                consumedLinks.append(linkToCheck);
            }
        }

        // add all the links as graphics items in the scene
        foreach(Link *linkToCheck, consumedLinks){
            scene->addItem(linkToCheck);
        }
```

So right now this doesn't check for duplicates in the `consumedLinks` list (obviously). Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**NOTE: I know that the pseudo-JSON above isn't valid**, it's just to give you an idea of the structure.

**NOTE2:** I rephrased and added detail and code to the question to make it clearer to understand what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't exactly do the same as @Riateche suggested, but something similar.

I basically created a `QList<QPair<QString,QString> >` so I could check for duplicates easily and then I created a list of `Link` based on the items in the `QPair` list. Something like:

```
        QList<Node*> existingNodes;
        QList<QPair<QString,QString> > linkPairList;
        QList<QGraphicsItem*> itemList = scene->items();

        foreach(QGraphicsItem *item, itemList){
            Node* tempNode = qgraphicsitem_cast<Node*>(item);
            if(tempNode){
                existingNodes.append(tempNode);
            }
        }

        foreach(QVariant nodesMap, allNodesList){
            QVariantMap node1 = nodesMap.toMap();
            QList<QVariant> nodeDetails = node1["node"].toList();
            QVariantMap allLinksMap = nodeDetails.at(9).toMap();


            QList<QVariant> linksList = allLinksMap["links"].toList();
            foreach(QVariant linkMap, linksList){
                QVariantMap details = linkMap.toMap();

                QPair<QString,QString>linkPair(details["fromNode"].toString(),details["toNode"].toString());
                QPair<QString,QString>reversedLinkPair(details["toNode"].toString(),details["fromNode"].toString());

                if(!linkPairList.contains(linkPair)){
                    // !dupe
                    if(!linkPairList.contains(reversedLinkPair)){
                        // !reversed dupe
                        linkPairList.append(linkPair);
                    }
                }
                qDebug()<<"number of pairs: "<<linkPairList.size();
            }

        }
        QPair<QString,QString> linkPairInList;
        foreach(linkPairInList, linkPairList){
            Node *savedFromNode;
            Node *savedToNode;
            foreach(Node* node, existingNodes){
                if(node->text()==linkPairInList.first){
                    savedFromNode=node;
                }
                if(node->text()==linkPairInList.second){
                    savedToNode=node;
                }
            }
            Link *newLink = new Link(savedFromNode,savedToNode, "input");
            scene->addItem(newLink);
        }
```

This is the **correct** answer because it solves what I needed to solve. Since I only got there because of @Riateche's comments, I +1'd his answer.

Answer (score 1):

`1.` Normalize links i.e. replace `(a, b)` to `(b, a)` when `b < a`. Each link should be represented as `(a, b)`, `a < b`.

`2.` Create a `QSet< QPair<Node*, Node *> >` variable and put all links into it. Each link object can be maked using `qMakePair(node1, node2)`. Since `QSet` is an qnique container, all duplicates will be removed automatically.

Comment: The `a` and `b` values are handled as `QStrings` up to the point I create the links. How would you adapt your code in that case?

Comment: Also, note that those node names are examples. They are not serialized in any way. They can be something like `Bread` and `Butter`...

Comment: You can use `QString::compare` to compare strings.